# JPQL returns all associated Entities

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to get Order[] Array which includes all Orders where the associated document isn't received.

I tried this query and it returns the right number of rows.

```
 @Query("Select o FROM Order o INNER JOIN o.properties p  INNER JOIN p.documents  d WHERE d.received = false")
    Order[] findUnreceivedOrders();
```

The problem is, the order objects in my array includes ALL documents not only the unreceived, but I want that the object only includes the unreceived document objects.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks for help!

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true,
        value = {"progress"})
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private String orderid;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userid;
    @Column(name = "entrydate")
    private java.sql.Date entrydate;
    @Column(name = "info")
    private String info;
    @Column
    private boolean complete;
    @Column(name= "cached")
    private boolean cached;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order")
    private List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
    private BillingAdress billingAdress;

    // Getter & Setter
```

**Property.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "properties")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true,
        value = {"progress"})
public class Property
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "propertyid", unique = true )
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;
    @Column(name = "zip")
    private String zip;
    @Column(name = "town")
    private String town;
    @Column
    private String house_number;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "property")
    private List<Landregisterfolio> landregisterfolios = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "userid" )
    private String userid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "property")
    private List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;

    @Column(name = "order_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String orderid;

//Getter & Setter
}
```

**Document.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String docid;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String docname;
    @Column(name = "received")
    private Boolean received;
    @Column(name = "requested")
    private Boolean requested;
    @Column(name ="last_contact")
    private Date lastContact;
    @Column(name ="intern_comment")
    private String intern_comment;
    @Column(name ="extern_comment")
    private String extern_comment;
    @Column(name="fees")
    private double fees;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_propertyid")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Property property;

    @Column(name = "property_propertyid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String propertyid;

//Getter & Setter

}
```

Comment: What orm implementation are you using: Hibernate, EclipseLink, another ORM?

Comment: Use `is false` instead of `= false`

Comment: @pdem I'm using hibernate

Comment: Try using "join fetch", it should work in hibernate.

Comment: @pdem used it and got MultipleBagFetchException. Changed my Lists to Sets and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pdem !

Used "join fetch", changed my lists to sets and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you can map `@ManyToOne` `Order` to your `Document` entity and after use for `Order` entity

```
@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula("(select d.id from documents d WHERE d.order_id = id AND d.received = false"))
List<Document> unreceivedDocuments;
```

Answer (score 0):

U have list of `Property` in `Order` and list of `Document` in `Property`. So if u have one `Document` with status not received in your list u will have this `Order`.

Comment: I know, but I only want the unreceived document in my list. So the order object should only include the unreceived objects not all.